# How can I open port 443 in Mac OS X 10.6?

Tags: macos, snow-leopard

I have a local apache running on my macbook pro and I need to run a SSL website on the local host. I have everything configured in Apache, but can't open port 443 on mac. I tried to add ipfw rule to allow 443 but it doesn't work.

Comment: Have you simply disabled the firewall entirely and made sure the server is really listening on that port? I've been shocked how many times that's been my problem.

Answer (score 4):

make sure 443 accessible from local and configured.

```
$ netstat -an|grep 443
```

allow 443 in ipfw

```
$ sudo ipfw add allow tcp from any to any 443
```

Comment: I did this, doesn't work. it shows me when I do ipfw list, but on nmap it doesn't show 443

Comment: @Stewie: Does it show up in the netstat output?  If not, the firewall doesn't matter, because nothing is listening for connections on port 443.

Comment: @Stewie nmap won't necessarily find all open ports, depending on how secure your system is.

Answer (score 1):

Open file /etc/apache2/httpd.conf

Look for line with listen 80

Add line           listen 443

Save and restart apache using          apachectl graceful

Check for any error in http.conf using apachectl configtest

Thank Bob at https://bobcares.com/blog/apache-not-listening-on-port-443/

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question. It's not about getting Apache to listen on 443, but *opening the port* on the built in firewall.

Comment: However given Gordon's comment it might be the correct one but t he op did not respond and his now totally left. We will never know